# Where are checksums stored in the database?

Tags: database, checksum

Where are checksums stored in the database? Is there any considerations to the limitations of how many checksums can be created at once in a mailing? If I send a checksum email to ~250,000 will that work without issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The checksum is an md5 hash of the value in the database field `civicrm_contact.hash`, the Contact ID, the current timestamp and the life-span.

Therefore, as long as the contact hash stays the same (it never changes, unless you do it manually), then you can generate as many tokens as necessary.

Once generated, checksums look like `xxxx_yyyy_zzzz`. The first part is the md5 hash, the second part is the timestamp of when it was generated, and the third part is the life-span. That way CiviCRM can easily lookup the contact.hash, and with the `yyyy` and `zzzz`, be able to recalculate/validate the `xxxx` part.

For reference, see `CRM/Contact/BAO/Contact/Utils.php`, the function `generateChecksum`.